# How do I test for a player's xp levels in a radius of 2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have the command

```
/give @p[lm=10] bow
```

set up in one command and

```
/xp -10L @p[lm=10] in another.
```

I need to know how to make the second command apply to only players
in a specific radius.

Answer (score 1):

It should just be `/xp -10L @p[lm=10,r=X]` where `X` is the number of blocks in the radius.